# multinomional linear regression model in pyspark error u'Field "label" does not exist.'

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I am new in pyspark and i was trying to make a multinomional linear regression model but got stuck in middle. Please help me.
these are the step i followed.

```
    lr_data=loan_data.select('int_rate','loan_amnt','term','grade','sub_grade','emp_length','verification_status','home_ownership','annual_inc','purpose','addr_state','open_acc')

    lr_data.printSchema()
    root
    |-- int_rate: string (nullable = true)
    |-- loan_amnt: integer (nullable = true)
    |-- term: string (nullable = true)
    |-- grade: string (nullable = true)
    |-- sub_grade: string (nullable = true)
    |-- emp_length: string (nullable = true)
    |-- verification_status: string (nullable = true)
    |-- home_ownership: string (nullable = true)
    |-- annual_inc: double (nullable = true)
    |-- purpose: string (nullable = true)
    |-- addr_state: string (nullable = true)
    |-- open_acc: string (nullable = true)
```

Here **int_rate** my target variable and rest of them are independent variable. Since target variable should not be string type so I transform this into string indexer and other I used pipeline method and transform with one hot encoder and then vector assembler. but first let's see my dataset.

```
   int_rate     loan_amnt   term    grade   sub_grade   emp_length   verification_status    home_ownership  annual_inc  purpose     addr_state  open_acc
    0   10.65%  5000.0  36 months   B   B2  10+ years   Verified     RENT   24000.0     credit_card     AZ  3
   1    15.27%  2500.0  60 months   C   C4  < 1 year    Source Verified     RENT    30000.0     car     GA  3
   2    15.96%  2400.0  36 months   C   C5  10+ years   Not Verified    RENT    12252.0     small_business  IL  2

 only three rows

   from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
    stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="int_rate", outputCol = "rate_ind")
    model=stringIndexer.fit(lr_data)
    lr_data2= model.transform(lr_data)
```

after doing this my int_rate variable is double type not numeric but I continued.

```
   ## build pipeline model
```

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=all_stages)

```
    ## fit pipeline model
   pipeline_mode = pipeline.fit(lr_data2)
   ## transform data
  lr_data_coded = pipeline_mode.transform(lr_data2)
 from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

  # feature columns
  feature_columns = lr_data_coded.columns[0:10]

  # build VectorAssembler instance
  vectorassembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=feature_columns,   outputCol='features')

 # transform data
  lr_data3 = vectorassembler.transform(lr_data_coded)
```

now all my transform data in the lr_data3 now I have to make a linear regression model. I first split my data into train and test data.

```
  #spilt into two partition 

  train_data, test_data = lr_data3.randomSplit([.7,.3], seed = 100)
  df=lr_data3.select("rate_ind","features",).show(5, truncate = False)
  # Import LinearRegression class
  from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
  lr = LinearRegression(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features")
  modelA = lr.fit(train_data, {lr.regParam:0.0})
```

now the error I am getting is u'Field "label" does not exist.'. ofcource I do not have any label colcum in my dataset. Please suggest me what can i do to run this model

Comment: The indexed target variable , 'rate_ind' shoud be labelCol.

Comment: Thanks Suresh :) I did but now this getting me very long error. some middle of something.

 Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: StringIndexer encountered NULL value. To handle or skip NULLS, try setting StringIndexer.handleInvalid.
 at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$5.apply(StringIndexer.scala:213)
 at  org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$5.apply(StringIndexer.scala:208)
 ... 17 more

Comment: Think, your int_rate column is having null values. check and impute the null values as per your requirements.

Comment: I check with dropna() command that time I couldn't get any NULL values. anyother method to check the null values like I have to check in my int_rate column ?
Many Thanks :)

Comment: Now I checked my whole dataset count  it is showing me 42538 but when I counted the int_rate column it showing me the count 42535. how can i solve this ??

Comment: maybe, there is duplicates in int_rate. you can check for that.

Comment: any idea How can i do that?? I think it must be NULL values 
just for the suggestion 
my linear regression is good so far?
I am very new in pyspark so don't know much about it